# How do I request permissions for web push notification

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm building a PWA and I'm trying to request push notification permissions.

I have this code in my messaging service:

```js
  requestPermission() {
    return this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.pipe(
      tap(token => {
        console.log('Store token to server: ', token);
      })
    );
  }
```

But it's not prompting me.  It never hits the console log in this line with the token:

[image]

However, I am getting the token but when I send a push notification via Postman I get the following:

```js
{
    "multicast_id": 33223323233,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure what I'm not doing correctly here.